# Did the SDS invent a new literary form?

Tags: history-of-literature

In 1965 Arthur Waskow "asked [Paul Booth] whether anyone had ever considered the possibility that the New Left was inventing a 'new literary form.'" (*Smoking Typewriters* 21, McMillian 2011; referencing SDS Records, Reel 5, Series 2A, No. 42, August 2, 1965) In McMillian's context, Waskow was probably referring to the  radical approach toward letter-sharing as a form of "dialogue and cross-fertilization" which characterized the Students for a Democratic Society. It could, however, be speaking to the style of underground press which rose out of that correspondence.

Are the SDS's epistles, or the underground press movement associated with the New Left, considered unique forms of literature?